# The Twist Group

Tags: group-theory

Let T be the set of "twists" that a curve can express. A twist of a curve is essentially a normal vector to the curve parameterized by the curve. The normal vector may include angle in 3D.

In a mobius strip there is a twist vector that simply is the normal vector to the strip. In 2D it would be simply a magnitude and sign, in 3D a magnitude and angle. The angle is protected in to a sign bit. Higher dimensions apply but is relatively irrelevant to this question.

The idea is that composing twists is a twist, there is the identity twist of not twisting, which can be considered a twist, and every twist has an inverse twist.

Hence twisting forms an abelian group under composition.

Has this been studied?

Specially what I'm interesting in is how 1D curves can be embedded in to higher dimensions and can be given different "twists" when they are done. E.g., The mobius strip and the normal strip both have the same 1D curve but when embedded in to 3D space they end up with different properties. These properties are due precisely because the 1D curve can be "twisted" idempotent(acting on the 1D curve it does nothing, but acting on the 3D embedded curve they give rise to different surfaces).

I'm seeing the Mobius strip vs the normal strip precisely as two different representations of the 1D curve where the representations are due to the twist group and these interact with embedded in particular ways.

(The curve itself embedded is irrelevant as when the mobius strip's width is shrunk to 0 it is the same curve as when the normal strip is shrunk... at least up to homotopy. Hence when we "flatten" out the curve it can give rise to different classes of surfaces in the embedded space. This seems to be precisely due to the fact that the 1D curves pass through the twisting group unaltered).

Comment: You might find it helpful to Google the "ribbon" braid group. Your idea seems related (but different).

Comment: @user1729 I believe it is different but ultimately by be similar. Braids are more about permutations while I'm specifically talk about how embedding curves in to higher dimensional spaces somehow express something innate about the embedding.  It may turn out that the extra dimensions are permutations of the lower dimensional curve, in some sense. That is, the extra dimensions allow for twists to take place. e.g., the 1D curve embedded in 3D give 3 - 1 = 2 unique types of twisting groups(partitions it in to two).

Comment: It was the "ribbon" bit I was really referring to. I wondered if the tools and techniques used here might give you some insight.

Comment: @user1729 I'm not really up on the brain group that much so I can't see how it might be related. Clearly there is a relationship but I'm not sure if what I'm describing is just some convoluted idea in braid theory or some obvious thing. This is just something that donned on me recently and was something I haven't see before.Our conception of the mobius strip stems directly from it's embedding and has nothing to do with the curve itself(in 1D, which is just a line without thickness nor space). But in 3D the curve can take on multiple chiral like forms(2). Hence the embedding itself does this.

Comment: So, in some sense we can apply a twist on the 1D curve, which does nothing but when embedded it does something. E.g., If C is the 1D curve and T is a twist, then T(C) = C. But if C is embedded by E then T(E(C)) != E(C). E.g., the mobius strip is not topologically equivalent to the normal strip. This is obvious of course, but what I'm thinking is that it is due to some type of equivalence class the the 1D curve represents and embedding in to higher dimensions parametrizes the equivalence class. This might be expressible in how knots also can be characterized by embedding in to higher dimension

Comment: It may all be exactly knot theory just from a different perspective... I just don't know enough about knot theory to determine this. If it is not I imagine there is still a deeper connection. Best I can tell is that what I'm seeing is has to do with the extra dimensions. V - E + F type of characterization. 1 - 1 + 2 = 2 which is the degree's of freedom the curve can take through different twists, in this case there are 2 twists, the normal and the mobius(e.g., + and - ). In 4D we would have still 2 possible variants a 1D curve could be expressed as since the V,E, and F won't change.